# List of strings: looking for a particular character

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following list with only strings in it.

```
appliances = ['blender', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster']
```

How do I generate a new list that is composed of the elements of the list appliance, that contains only the strings that have the letter v in it?  After running it through, the new list looks like this:

```
short = ['oven', 'microwave']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
short = [x for x in appliances if 'v' in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

The tools you need are list comprehensions (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the `in` operator (http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in).